# How to get positions of tikz curve to lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to draw the following figure, that is to get the positions of two separate lines (`curve to` line) and then draw a line between them.

[image]

My code,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\L{1.5}
    \draw (0,0) to[bend left] (\L,0) node[pos=0.5] (a) {};
    \draw (\L,0) to[bend left] (0,0) node[pos=0.5] (b) {};
    \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
    \fill[red] (a) circle(1.5pt);
    \fill[blue] (a) circle(1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

only produce the following one.

[image]

How to get points (a list of them would be better) of **different** (for maximum flexibility) lines so that I can use these points later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to place the nodes inside the path when you use `pos=0.5`. (For straight lines `--` you can be more sloppy.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\L{1.5}
    \draw (0,0) to[bend left] node[pos=0.5,draw,fill=red,circle,inner sep=2pt] (a) {} (\L,0)
    to[bend left]  node[pos=0.5,draw,fill=blue,circle,inner sep=2pt] (b) {}(0,0);
    \draw[densely dashed] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you tweak it a tiny bit, it becomes closer to the desired screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=#1}]
    \def\L{2.5}
    \draw (0,0) to[bend left=45] node[pos=0.5,bullet=red] (a) {} (\L,0)
    to[bend left=45]  node[pos=0.5,bullet=blue] (b) {}(0,0);
    \draw[densely dashed] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid](6,4)
    \pcarc[arcangle=-60](0,2)(6,2)\ncput{\Cnode[fillcolor=red]{A}}
    \pcarc[arcangle=60](0,2)(6,2)\ncput{\Cnode[fillcolor=blue]{B}}
    \ncline[linestyle=dashed]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Feature: The dashed lines are evenly distributed. Nice?

Comment: Sorry for interchanging the dot color. My eyes are not so sensitive to colors.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `to path` operation, the syntax is to place the nodes **between** the two coordinates. And it is not necessary to load the `positioning` library to place the two nodes in the middle of the path.

Indeed, I quoted page 157 of the 3.0.1a manual

> **Nodes on to–paths.**
>   It is possible to add nodes to the paths constructed by a **to** operation. To do so, you specify the nodes between the **to** keyword and the coordinate *(if there are options to the to operation, these come first)*. The effect of `(a) to node {x} (b)` *(typically)* is the same as if you had written `(a) --node {x} (b)`, namely that the node is placed on the to.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={draw=black,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},
    bend left=60]
    \def\L{1.5}
    \draw (0,0) to node[fill=red] (a) {}(\L,0) ;
    \draw (\L,0) to node[fill=blue] (b) {}(0,0) ;
    \draw[densely dashed] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: to node]