# Coordinate/node command doesn't work with \draw to?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I want to draw a curved line between two points but I can't define coordinates if I'm not using --. Is that deliberate or am I doing something wrong?

So, to explain better. If I use the following code:

```
\draw ($ (A) - (-0.5,0.5) $) -- ($ (A) - (5,10) $) coordinate[pos=0.4] (E);
```

I get a line using:

```
\draw[color=red] (0,0) -- (E.center);
```

But not if I use this (which I want):

```
\draw ($ (A) - (-0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (A) - (5,10) $) coordinate[pos=0.4] (E);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Complete code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\title{TikZ-test}

\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (-5,-0.25){};
\node (B) at (5,-0.25){};
\node (C) at (-1.2,1){};
\node (D) at (1.2,1){};

\draw[line width=1mm] (A.center) -- (B.center);

\draw[line width=1mm] (C) -- (D);
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,1) -- (0,2);
\draw[line width=1mm] (A) -- (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (B);
\draw[line width=1mm,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\draw ($ (A) - (-0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (A) - (5,10) $) coordinate[pos=0.4] (E);

\draw ($ (B) - (0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (B) - (5,10) $);

\draw[color=red] (0,0) -- (E.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `pos` syntax does not work with arbitrary curves, but you can, of course, use `decorations.markings` to make it work.

Comment: By adding \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes} I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pos` syntax does not work with arbitrary curves, but you can, of course, use `decorations.markings` to make it work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mark pos/.style args={#1 with #2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {#2}}}}]
\node (A) at (-5,-0.25){};
\node (B) at (5,-0.25){};
\node (C) at (-1.2,1){};
\node (D) at (1.2,1){};

\draw[line width=1mm] (A.center) -- (B.center);

\draw[line width=1mm] (C) -- (D);
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,1) -- (0,2);
\draw[line width=1mm] (A) -- (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (B);
\draw[line width=1mm,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\draw[mark pos=0.4 with {\coordinate (E);}] ($ (A) - (-0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (A) - (5,10) $);

\draw ($ (B) - (0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (B) - (5,10) $);

\draw[color=red] (0,0) -- (E.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**NOTE**: [You could also to place the nodes inside the path when you use `pos=0.5`. (For straight lines `--` you can be more sloppy.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464930/121799). `decorations.markings` always works, also for more complicated paths (unless the path has high curvature).

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple syntax error.

It is possible to place `coordinates` or `nodes` in a To Path operation but for this you must place them between the two coordinates of the operation *(See page 161 of Tikz manual 3.1)*.

I quote:

> **Nodes on to–paths**. It is possible to add nodes **to** the paths constructed by a to operation. To do so, you specify the nodes between
>   the to keyword and the coordinate (if there are options to the **to**
>   operation, these come first). The effect of **(a) to node {x} (b)**
>   (typically) is the same as if you had written **(a) --node {x} (b)**,
>   namely that the node is placed on the to.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document} 



%\title{TikZ-test}

\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (-5,-0.25){};
\node (B) at (5,-0.25){};
\node (C) at (-1.2,1){};
\node (D) at (1.2,1){};

\draw[line width=1mm] (A.center) -- (B.center);

\draw[line width=1mm] (C) -- (D);
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,1) -- (0,2);
\draw[line width=1mm] (A) -- (-1,0) -- (1,0) -- (B);
\draw[line width=1mm,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\draw ($ (A) - (-0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] coordinate[pos=0.4] (E)($ (A) - (5,10) $) ;

\draw ($ (B) - (0.5,0.5) $) to [out=270,in=0] ($ (B) - (5,10) $);

\draw[color=red] (0,0) -- (E.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```